Reattaching old hardwood floor to replaced joists
I had to replace four 15 ft. 2x12 joists in my basement from Termite damage. This is below a 12’x 12’ living room. Now I have some slight “bounce” to the floor in certain areas.
This house was built in 1954 and does not have a subfloor.  The floor is 1/2 oak tongue & groove.
I have not attached the floor in anyway to the new joists.  I did however add some pine shims between the top of joists and the underside of the floor which does help, (temp fix). Some areas of floor are not super tight to joists.  This couldn’t seem to be avoided by me.
I’ve seen a screw product for squeaking hardwood floors.  This is not an application for my needs, but looks close.  Some say never screw these floors down from the top anyway. This would require too many screws. They would be most likely be noticeable too.
Are there any suggestions out there as to what I can do? Thank you.

54 joists and 2024 joists are not the same 2x12.  You probably dropped at least a 1/4 inch smaller(11 3/4 to 11 1/2), maybe more.  Can either raise the joists at the ends where they sit or add an extra shim on top of the joists to fit better/tighter to the floor.

The bounce is the floor itself.   Most of area where the floor meets the joists is snug.
Just some area in between has possibly an 1/8 space or less.   Certainly enough over a small span to give a slight bounce. Enough to be a slight annoyance. I do have full access from underneath. Some shimming has been helpful. It just doesn’t seem to be a clean and permanent solution.

Some ideas:

Wait. The wood will probably settle over time and the issue goes away. Whether this is the right move depends on which is flatter, the flooring or the framing.

More shims. Or sistered rails. Or whatever. You could screw one-by boards or plywood scrap to the sides of the joists, snug with the flooring, to close gaps.

Caulk or construction adhesive, injected into the gaps. I'd probably favor something squishy, like that sealant for rain gutters that stays gooey. Anything rigid might go to battle with the wood, which will tend to move seasonally. Decide whether you should weigh the flooring down while it cures based on the flatness of the floor one way or the other.

Finish nails. Probably ring shank or paneling nails for best hold. Pre-drill through the flooring, then set and fill with putty.


